# How to stop scroll the main content area in core-scaffold

Tags: css, polymer

I am trying to develop a page which looks similar to the one shown [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-scaffold/demo.html) and [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-scaffold.html#core-scaffold.summary). So Inside my app where `<div>Main content goes here...</div>` is displayed, I have created a table and inserted it using another DataTables API. I selected the options inside datatables api such that the table has fixed table headers and only table rows will scroll.

The problem in my page is, after i reach end of table, the main content area also scrolling. Is there anything i have to add so that `<div>Main content goes here...</div>` will only consume a fixed height. ie what ever available on screen. I tried giving the `height:95%` but when the table inside is large, the div is expanding completely.

Added screenshots to show the problem: [Here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B71T1vBlMJ88fkpFeFNrajJmbXB3bGNxaXF1V2k1Rjl0Q0RxRFVfeUszQjJJN3ZaaFRBb1k&usp=sharing)

Comment: do you mind uploading a screenshot so we can get a better understanding of what is happening to you. I'm not sure I'm understanding because it seems like you want your main content goes here div to be fixed as well

Comment: Sure., I added couple of screenshots in the drive folder https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B71T1vBlMJ88fkpFeFNrajJmbXB3bGNxaXF1V2k1Rjl0Q0RxRFVfeUszQjJJN3ZaaFRBb1k&usp=sharing See if that explains my problem. I removed all text from the table.

Comment: you have a wrapper? Cause if it cant fit in anything, it will use the size of your screen, instead of the div. So your table will indeed be pushed out of the screen.

Comment: try this position:fixed; left:0; top:0; height: whatever value you want;
you may need to adjust the left and top so it sits where you want however, let me know if it works

Comment: Yes! Thats seems to address the problem. That gives me a fixed heigh table and able to scroll inside the table only. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: If you don't mind please give me the best answer for my response so that I receive credit. @Srikanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copied answer from previously written comment. Under OP

```
Position:fixed; 
left:0; 
top:0; 
height: value;
```